# Reflections - Get package classes in order of @Order annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, package

I am currently looping through the classes in a package like this :

```
for (var entityClass : new Reflections("com.something.someotherthing").getSubTypesOf(Entity.class))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

I added an `@Order` annotation to each class and I would like this loop to traverse the package in the order of those annotations.  How can that be done?

Comment: Where does this `@Order` annotation come from?

Comment: org.springframework.core.annotation.Order, it's really just a basic annotation with an int parameter which represents the order in which i would like the package to be traversed

Comment: Reflections and Spring are two unrelated libraries. Spring provides a `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator`. Use it to sort whatever is returned by `getSubTypesOf`.

Comment: I will look into that thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` as suggested and extracted this logic to a utility method as below :

```
public static ArrayList<Class<? extends Entity>> getOrderedClassList(String packageName)
{
    var entityClasses = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Entity>>(
        new Reflections(packageName).getSubTypesOf(Entity.class));

    AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(entityClasses);

    return entityClasses;
}
```